# What is the best way to parallelise this code?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that I would like to maximise using python. However, the evaluation of this function is fairly slow and I would like to find a way to speed it up by parallelising this code. I'm not very familiar with how to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

In short, I have a `cost()` function that is then optimised using some library e.g. `scipy.optimize`. This function evaluates some other function `do_calculation()` 100 times and then averages these results (the method of this other function doesn't matter, but the results have some statistical spread). This average is the quantity I want to maximise. However, evaluating it is actually quite expensive especially 100s of times, so I would like to parallelise the evaluation of that mean. How could I go about doing this in an efficient way?

```
def function():
    val_list = []
    for i in range(100):
        val = do_calculation()
        val_list.append(val)
    return np.mean(np.array(val_list))
```

I was thinking about using `multiprocessing` to split up this loop, but then how do I rejoin all the values on different processors to calculate a final mean?

Comment: Please always include the [tag:numpy] tag when asking NumPy questions, as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki. NumPy introduces its own data structures and idioms.

Comment: You could simply use [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - it'll handle everything for you. Also note that there's no need to store all `val`ues to compute the mean: you could compute it as a running sum like `the_mean += val / 100`.

Comment: You could also check out dask. There are a number of “getting started” tutorials out there for all of the options. All of the options will be hard, but worth learning. See the stackoverflow guide to [ask] - generally questions asking for recs or guides to a new domain will be closed as they’re not specific and lead to opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiprocessing you can use a process pool to map your function to a list of possible arguments

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def do_calculation(idx):
    pass # write your code here

N_PROC=2
def function():
    val_list = []
    with Pool(N_PROC) as p:
        val_list = p.map(do_calculation, range(100))
    return np.mean(np.array(val_list))
```

Actually for this case, where you are computing the average (and that does not depend on the order), you could also use [imap_unordered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered), in some cases may be advantageous, if the jobs take considerably different times.